# Symfony VichUploader can't display an image of an entity

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle

i'm new in symfony and i try to display an image in a view with Vich Uploader but don't know how to.
I have an entity Brand with a logo related (OneToMany) to an entity Ship.
When i try to display the logo of the brand in the view (show.html.twig) of Ship the logo is not displayed, I've no error in console/symfony and twig part with the img tag don't appear in the inspector.

I can diplay all my logo by a findAll() but can't find a way to only display the brand logo of the ship selected.

Any idea?

Ship entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ShipRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ShipRepository::class)
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Ship
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Brand::class, inversedBy="ships")
     */
    private $brand;
```

Brand entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\BrandRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BrandRepository::class)
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Brand
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Ship::class, mappedBy="brand")
     */
    private $ships;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $logo;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="brand_logo", fileNameProperty="logo")
     * @var File
     */
    private $logoFile;


    public function getLogo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->logo;
    }

    public function setLogo(?string $logo): self
    {
        $this->logo = $logo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLogoFile()
    {
        return $this->logoFile;
    }

    public function setLogoFile(File $logo = null)
    {
        $this->logoFile = $logo;

        // VERY IMPORTANT:
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using Doctrine,
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be calles and the file is lost
        if ($logo) {
            // if 'updatedAt' is not defined in your entity, use another property
            $this->createdAt  = new \DateTime('now');
        }
    }
```

ShipController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Front;

use App\Data\SearchData;
use App\Entity\Ship;
use App\Entity\Brand;
use App\Entity\ShipImages;
use App\Form\SearchType;
use App\Repository\ShipRepository;
use App\Repository\BrandRepository;
use App\Repository\ShipImagesRepository;
use App\Form\ShipType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/ship")
 */
class ShipController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="admin_ship_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(ShipRepository $shipRepository, Request $request): Response
    {
        $data = new SearchData();
        $data->page = $request->get('page', 1);
        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, $data);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $ships = $shipRepository->findSearch($data);
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return new JsonResponse([
                'content' => $this->renderView('main/_ship.html.twig', ['ship_list' => $ships]),
                'pagination' => $this->renderView('main/_pagination.html.twig', ['ship_list' => $ships]),
            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('admin/ship/index.html.twig', [
            'ship_list' => $ships,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/show/{id}", name="admin_ship_show", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function shipShow(Ship $ship): Response
    {
        $ship->getBrand()->getLogoFile();
        //dd($ship);

        return $this->render('admin/ship/show.html.twig', [
            'ship' => $ship,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Show.html.twig :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}shipName{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="main-content">
        <h2>{{ ship.name }}</h2>
        <div class="second-wrapper">
            <div class="image-holder">
                <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(ship, 'shipViewFile') }}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="first-wrapper">
            <div class="ship-model">
                <div class="model-block-content">
                    <h4>Type</h4>
                    <p>{{ ship.type }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="model-block-content">
                    <h4>Manufacturer</h4>
                    <p>{{ ship.brand }}</p>
                    {% for brand in ship %}
                        <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(brand, 'logo') }}"/>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
```

Comment: Found the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777825/problems-with-vichuploaderbundle-render-image-using-twig